# I developed an android application and generated signed APK but it doesn't appear in device

Tags: java, android

When i install and open my app everything is fine but the app doesn't appear with the device's app liste ! I'm working with android studio and i'm working at an application not a game.

Comment: This should be a problem of the device or you eyes.

Comment: Did you try pressing the run button? Or going to Run > Run 'app'

Answer (score 0):

When you generate a signed apk, it does what is says, generate a signed apk and save it in the folder you specified in your computer.

It doesnt make it appear on your device.

If you wanna make it appear on your device, just press the Run button.

Comment: No I mean when I install it in my phone it opens with automatic launch activity thats good, but it doesn't shows the icon of the app in the phone's list of installed apps.

Comment: have you specify the applicationId ?@ Ousama

Comment: Yes I set the applicationId When defining the package name.